# Ajax doesn't work on multiple divs

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Probably this question is very dumb, but i've tried solving for days and still couldn't get it done. **Whoever can solve this please name a price and give me you paypal, money goes to you** :).Basically, i want to put a add to wish list button to a series of div, id = "imgforplaces_thumbnail" (see my php function), the while loop in php function will then generate a number of div "imgforplaces_thumbnail", i.e. 12. I have tried to var_dump($row['id']); for each different item in the while loop, they have shown i.e. 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc.Basically the add to wish list button, class ="addbutton","deletebutton", when i click on it, will do an ajax call, either Addtobucketlist() or Deletefrombucketlist() (see header). depending on the status of checkifadded(), it will show or hide class "addbutton" or "deletebutton". Now my problem is that when i execute the codes, when i click on the first check button, it simply runs the last check button function!i.e. $row['id']=6.

One thing worth to note is that if i am not using multiple divs, it works like magic! but not when there are more than one div "imgforplaces_thumbnail"

You can see demo here: http://utourpia.me/php/dreamtrip.php

This is my header:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.addBucket').submit(function(e) {
            Addtobucketlist();
            e.preventDefault(); 
        }); 
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.deleteBucket').submit(function(e) {
            Deletefrombucketlist();
            e.preventDefault(); 
        }); 
    });
```

i will do an ajax call:

```
function Addtobucketlist()
{
    hideshow('loading',1);
    error(0);
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://utourpia.me/php/addtobucketlist.php",      
    data: $('.addBucket').serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg){

        if(parseInt(msg.status)==1)
        {
            if ($('.addbutton').is(":visible")){
            //hide the form
            $('.addbutton').fadeOut(1);                 
            //show the success message
            $('.deletebutton').fadeIn(1);
            }
            else {
            //hide the form
            $('.addbutton').fadeIn(1);                  
            //show the success message
            $('.deletebutton').fadeOut(1);
            }
        }
        else if(parseInt(msg.status)==0)
        {
            error(1,msg.txt);
        }

        hideshow('loading',0);
    }
});

}

function Deletefrombucketlist()
{
    hideshow('loading',1);
    error(0);
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://utourpia.me/php/deletefrombucketlist.php",     
    data: $('.deleteBucket').serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg){

        if(parseInt(msg.status)==1)
        {
            if ($('.addbutton').is(":visible")){
            //hide the form
            $('.addbutton').fadeOut(1);                 
            //show the success message
            $('.deletebutton').fadeIn(1);
            }
            else {
            //hide the form
            $('.addbutton').fadeIn(1);                  
            //show the success message
            $('.deletebutton').fadeOut(1);
            }
        }
        else if(parseInt(msg.status)==0)
        {
            error(1,msg.txt);
        }

        hideshow('loading',0);
    }
});

}
```

this is my php function:

```
$result = mysql_query("select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from places order by id asc limit 12");

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<div id=imgforplaces_thumbnail>';

$location_id = $row['id'];

if (check_if_added($users_id, $location_id) == "yes")
{ 
echo '<div class=addbutton>';
echo '<form class=deleteBucket action="http://utourpia.me/php/deletefrombucketlist.php" method=post>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="Delete1" value='.$location_id.' />';
echo '<input type="image" src="../images/checked.png" name="Delete" value="delete"><img id=loading src="http://utourpia.me/images/loading.gif" alt="working.." />';
echo '</form>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="deletebutton">';
echo '<form class=addBucket action="http://utourpia.me/php/addtobucketlist.php" method=post>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="Add1" value='.$location_id.' />';
echo '<input type="image" src="../images/haventchecked.png" name="Add" value="add"><img id=loading src="http://utourpia.me/images/loading.gif" alt="working.." />';
echo '</form>';
echo '</div>';
}
else if (check_if_added($users_id, $location_id) == "no")
{
echo '<div class=addbutton>';
echo '<form class=addBucket action="http://utourpia.me/php/addtobucketlist.php" method=post>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="Add1" value='.$location_id.' />';
echo '<input type="image" src="../images/haventchecked.png" name="Add" value="add"><img id=loading src="http://utourpia.me/images/loading.gif" alt="working.." />';
echo '</form>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="deletebutton">';
echo '<form class=deleteBucket action="http://utourpia.me/php/deletefrombucketlist.php" method=post>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="Delete1" value='.$location_id.' />';
echo '<input type="image" src="../images/checked.png" name="Delete" value="delete"><img id=loading src="http://utourpia.me/images/loading.gif" alt="working.." />';
echo '</form>';
echo '</div>';
}   
    echo '</div>'; //end div imgforplaces_thumbnail 

            echo '<br />';
        }
```

Comment: id's must be unique. You currently have `n` number of `<div id=imgforplaces_thumbnail>`. Also, with multiple elements with the same class, you need to specify which one, so you don't get all or last. That is where `this` or `$(this)` can be utilized.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to note from your sample page and question:

1. $(document).ready only needs to be used once on your page.  You have it several times.
2. IDs have to be unique.
3. You don't need to wrap your add and delete images in forms.  Just add a class or unique ID to each and add a click event instead of submitting the form.  Alternatively, if you want to keep the forms, call e.preventDefault() immediately to prevent the form submission before you perform your action.  However it seems like you want to perform these actions asynchronously, in which case you should remove the form and put a click event on each image which performs your AJAX request.
4. If your DOM elements are being created after document.ready, consider using [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead of click.